# exporting and importing a const in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm getting stuck at the step that requires me to create a `firebase/Context.jsx` file, which I have done as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export default FirebaseContext;
```

Then in `index.js`, I try to import `Firebase Context` as:

```
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/firebase/Context';
```

I get an error that says:

> Attempted import error: 'FirebaseContext' is not exported from
>   './components/firebase/Context

How do I export/import in react?

Comment: Context only exports a single default, you are calling that firebase in your import. There is not other component to import from that file

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: If you mean I should delete the reference to Firebase in the import statement, so that it only imports the curly braces, i already tried that and I get the same error

Comment: When you export a default object you don’t use the curly braces. That is for importing a specific component of a file that exports multiple components. You just need ‘import FirebaseContext from...

Comment: I updated the question since this has nothing to do with firebase, this is just es6 import/export basics

Comment: why did you delete the example from the other post that i shared. it's the first result that comes up for this error message. it may help others find this solution?

Comment: Because the error you are getting has nothing to do with that example.

Comment: It's the first result that comes (and there are many after it) that got to those solutions. Others encountering this problem no longer have the benefit of that context because of the changes you made. I don't have time to reinstate my post.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the error you posted, in `firebase/Context.jsx` change it to :

```
import React from 'react';

export const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);
```

Then import

```
import { FirebaseContext } from './components/firebase/Context';
```

Alternatively, leave `firebase/Context.jsx` file as it is (exporting a default) and change the import to

```
import  FirebaseContext  from './components/firebase/Context';
```

Comment: This solution produces an error that says: TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default is not a constructor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor)

Comment: This error is generated regardless of which way I set up the Context file

Comment: This is now a different error. You should set up a different question for that. The problem you posted has been solved. To fix the webpack error you will probably need to share the rest of the file where you set up the context and your firebase config file.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer since it answered your original question.